# Correct terminology in type theory: types, type constructors, kinds/sorts and values

Tags: terminology, type-systems, data-types, type-theory

In an answer to a [previous question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/255696/what-is-a-lifted-representation/255705?noredirect=1#comment516638_255705), a small debate started about correct terminology for certain constructs. As I did not find a question (other than [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/119073/values-types-kinds-and) or [that](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/211364/generic-name-for-types-and-values), which is not quite the right thing) to address this clearly, I am making this new one.

The questionable terms and their relationships are: *type, type constructor, type parameter, kinds or sorts, and values*.

I also checked [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory) for type theory, but that didn't clarify it much either.

So for the sake of having a good reference answer and to check my own understanding:

- How are these things defined properly?
- What is the difference between each of these things?
- How are they related to each other?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Alright, let's go one by one.

### Values

Values are the concrete pieces of data that programs evaluate and juggle. Nothing fancy, some examples might be

- `1`
- `true`
- `"fizz buzz foo bar"`

### Types

A nice description for a type is "a classifier for a value". A type is a little bit of information about what that value will be at runtime, but indicated at compile time.

For example if you tell me that `e : bool` at compile time, and I'll know that `e` is either `true` or `false` during runtime, nothing else! Because types classify values nicely like this, we can use this information to determine some basic properties of your program.

For example, if I ever see you adding `e` and `e'` when `e : int` and `e' : String`, then I know something is a bit off! In fact I can flag this and throw an error at compile time, saying "Hey, that doesn't make any sense at all!".

A more powerful type system allows for more interesting types which classify more interesting values. For example, let's consider some function

```
f = fun x -> x
```

It's pretty clear that `f : Something -> Something`, but what should that `Something` be? In a boring type system, we'd have to specify something arbitrary, like `Something = int`. In a more flexible type system, we could say

```
f : forall a. a -> a
```

That is to say "for any `a`, `f` maps an `a` to an `a`". This let's us use `f` more generally and write more interesting programs.

Moreover, the compiler is going to check actually satisfying the classifier we've given it, if `f = fun x -> true` then we have a bug and the compiler will say so!

So as a tldr; a type is a compile time constraint on the values an expression can be at runtime.

### Type Constructor

Some types are related. For example a list of integers is very similar to a list of strings. This is almost like how `sort` for integers is almost like `sort` for strings. We can imagine a sort of factory that builds these almost-the-same types by generalizing over their differences and building them upon demand. That's what a type constructor is. It's kind of like a function from types to types, but a little more limited.

The classic example is a generic list. A type constructor for is just the generic definition

```
 data List a = Cons a (List a) | Nil
```

Now `List` is a function which maps a type `a` to a list of values of that type! In Java-land I think these are perhaps called "generic classes"

### Type Parameters

A type parameter is just the type passed to a type constructor (or function). Just like in the value level we'd say `foo(a)` has a parameter `a` just like how `List a` has a type parameter `a`.

### Kinds

Kinds are a bit tricky. The basic idea is that certain types are similar. For example, we have all the primitive types in java `int`, `char`, `float`... which all behave as if they have the same "type". Except, when we're speaking of the classifiers for types themselves, we call the classifiers kinds. So `int : Prim`, `String : Box`, `List : Boxed -> Boxed`.

This system gives nice concrete rules about what sort of types we can use where, just like how types govern values. It'd clearly be nonsense to say

```
 List<List>
```

or

```
 List<int>
```

In Java since `List` needs to be applied to a concrete type to be used like that! If we look at their kinds `List : Boxed -> Boxed` and since `Boxed -> Boxed /= Boxed`, the above is a kind error!

Most of the time we don't really think about kinds and just treat them as "common sense", but with fancier type systems it's something important to think about.

A little illustration of what I've been saying so far

```
 value   : type : kind  : ...
 true    : bool : Prim  : ...
 new F() : Foo  : Boxed : ...
```

### Better Reading Than Wikipedia

If you're interested in this sort of thing, I'd highly recommend investing a good textbook. Type theory and PLT in general is pretty vast and without a coherent base of knowledge you (or at least I) can wander around without getting anywhere for months.

Two of my favorite books are

- Types and Programming Language - Ben Pierce
- Practical Foundations of Programming Languages - Bob Harper

Both are excellent books that introduce what I've just talked about and much more in beautiful, well explained detail.

Comment: Types are sets?  I like "classifier" better, but you don't explain what this means, and without a good understanding of what a type is, the rest of your answer sort of falls down.

Comment: @RobertHarvey How does it look now, I've dropped all mentions of sets :)

Comment: Much better....

Comment: @RobertHarvey I find the view of types as sets very intuitive. E.g. The type `int` in Java consists of a set of 2^64 distinct values. The analogy with sets breaks down when subtypes get involved, but it's a good enough initial intuition, especially once you consider algebraic data types (e.g. a union of two types can contain any of the members of either type; it's the union of those sets).

Comment: @Doval: If I write a class that describes a Customer, it's probably going to represent a "set" of customers, since I'm going to make a collection of instances.  But saying that a Customer is a Type because it describes a "set" of customers is a tautology; it seems obvious.  What is more interesting is that a Customer type describes the *characteristics* of a customer.  Using "set" to explain this seems more... abstract than it actually is.  Unless, perhaps, you are a mathematician.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't see what makes the "classifier" viewpoint any less of a tautology. In both cases you're describing which values are valid for an operation. By defining a Customer class with fields `name` and `age`, you're saying you're not interested in values that don't contain either of those fields or that contain additional fields.

Comment: Yeah, but calling that a "set" of customers just seems counter-intuitive. That's what a collection is for.

Answer (score 2):

> How are these things defined properly?

They are properly defined by rigid, academic mathematical backing, providing strong assertions as to what they are, how they work, and what is guaranteed.

But programmers largely don't need to know that. They need to understand the concepts.

#### Values

Let's start with values, since everything builds from there. Values are the data used in computing. Depending on the approach, they're the values that everyone is familiar with: 42, 3.14, "How now brown cow", the personnel record for Jenny down in Accounting, etc.

Other interpretations of values are *symbols*. Most programmers understand these symbols to be the "values" of an enumeration. `Left` and `Right` are symbols for the enum `Handedness` (ignoring ambidextrous people and fish).

Regardless of the implementation, values are the different things that the language works with to perform calculations.

#### Types

The problem with values is that not all calculations are legal for all values. `42 + goat` doesn't really make sense.

This is where types come into play. Types are metadata that define subsets of values. The `Handedness` enum above is a good example. This type says "only `Left` and `Right` may be used here". This allows programs to determine very early that certain operations will result in error.

Another practical use to consider is that under the hood, computers work with bytes. The byte 42 might mean the number 42, or it might mean the character *, or it might mean Jenny from Accounting. Types also (in practical use, not theoretical so much) help define the encoding for the underlying collection of bytes used by computers.

#### Kinds

And here's where we start going a little out there. So, when a programming language has a variable that refers to a type, what type does **it** have?

In Java and C# for example, it has the type `Type` (which has the type `Type`, which has... and so on all the way down). This is the concept behind *kinds*. In some languages, you can do a bit more useful things with a Type variable than Java and C#. Once that happens it becomes useful to say "I want a value that is a Type, but is also some **kind** of `IEnumerable<int>`". Ta-da! Kinds.

Most programmers can think of kinds like Java and C# generic constraints. Consider `public class Foo<T> where T: IComparable{}`. In a language with kinds, the `T: kindOf(IComparable)` variable declaration becomes legal; not just a special thing you can do in class and function declarations.

#### Type Constructors

Perhaps unsurprisingly, type constructors are simply *constructors for types*. "But how do you construct a type? Types just *are*.". Eh... not so much.

Also unsurprisingly, it's pretty difficult to build *all* of the different useful subsets of values any computer program will ever use. Type constructors work to help allow programmers to "build" those subsets in meaningful ways.

The most ubiquitous example of a type constructor is an array definition: `int[4]`. Here you're specifying `4` to the type constructor, which uses the value to build you an array of `int`s with 4 entries. If you specified a different input type, you'd get a different output type.

Generics are another form of type constructor, taking another type as their input.

In many languages there is a type constructor like `P -> R` to build a type that represents a function that takes type `P` and returns type `R`.

Now, the context will determine if a "function that returns a type" is a type constructor or not. In my (admittedly limited) experience, the line is "can you use this type at compile time?". Yes? Type constructor. No? Just a function.

#### Type Parameter

So you remember the parameters passed to Type Constructors? They're commonly known as Type Parameters, since the common form of a Type Constructor is `Type[param]` or `Type<param>`.

Comment: Could you clarify/extend the section about 'Kinds'? In Haskell, a type has kind `*`, while a type constructor (with one argument) has kind `* -> *`.  Constraints such as `(Num a) => a` (meaning "any type `a` that is an instance of the `Num` typeclass") are not themselves kinds. The typeclass `Num` is not a 'kind' itself, but has the kind `* -> Constraint`. I find it difficult to relate the Haskell idea of a 'kind' (which I assume is closely related to kinds in type theory?) to the examples you give.

Comment: I should say, ghci's `:kind` command gives the kind of `Num` as `* -> Constraint`. That could be specific to GHC, I don't know.

Comment: @JohnBartholomew - Haskell Kinds are more of "signatures for Type Constructors". Unfortunately, my Haskell isn't nearly to the point where I would be comfortable talking too much about the particulars.